# Parameter order in callback function

Tags: c++, event-handling

I was watching this C++Con talk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e8SyxB3_mnw&t=2933s&ab_channel=CppCon
where something like the following code was given (https://godbolt.org/z/av4Tbn):

```cpp
struct Handler {
  void handle(int x, int y, int z);

  static void callback0(void *instance, int x, int y, int z) {
    static_cast<Handler *>(instance)->handle(x, y, z);
  }

  static void callback1(int x, int y, int z, void *instance) {
    static_cast<Handler *>(instance)->handle(x, y, z);
  }
};

auto c0 = Handler::callback0;
auto c1 = Handler::callback1;
```

That code produces the following assembly:

```
Handler::callback0(void*, int, int, int):
        jmp     Handler::handle(int, int, int)
Handler::callback1(int, int, int, void*):
        mov     r8d, edi
        mov     rdi, rcx
        mov     ecx, edx
        mov     edx, esi
        mov     esi, r8d
        jmp     Handler::handle(int, int, int)
c1:
        .quad   Handler::callback1(int, int, int, void*)
c0:
        .quad   Handler::callback0(void*, int, int, int)
```

Clearly callback0 is the preferred version here, but I do not understand what's happening "under the hood" in callback1? Can someone elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `callback0()`, the arguments are being passed in via CPU registers in the exact order that `handle()` is expecting them to be, where `instance` becomes `handler`'s `this` pointer, so there is no need to rearrange any of values, hence why the `jmp` is used by itself.

In `callback1`, the arguments have to be rearranged into the correct CPU registers where `handle()` is expecting them, before the `jmp` can then be invoked.

This is related to how [argument passing in various calling conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/argument-passing-and-naming-conventions?view=vs-2019) works.